# TextEdit wants to save as RTFD because of graphics, but I have used no graphics

Tags: textedit

I have been copying and pasting lots of contact info into a Textedit file.
I have been saving as I go along and it saves as .RTF
Now suddenly it says:

> This document contains graphics and will be saved using RTFD (RTF with graphics) format. RTFD documents are not compatible with some applications. Save anyway?

I have not intentionally put graphics onto document.  How can I find the 'graphic' and delete it?

Answer (score 4):

Try showing package contents in Finder and deleting all the image files.

[image]

You can then either move the rtf file outside the rtfd folder, or open the rtfd file in TextEdit, duplicate it, and save it as rtf.